# Searching strings using Regex in C#

Tags: .net, regex

I have following string returned from an HTTP request

```
"keyverified=yes connected=no now=1347429501 debug=Not connected and no params";
```

Now i want to extract different key value combinations using regex. I have tried like

```
var regString = @"keyverified=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)";
        var regex = new Regex(regString, RegexOptions.Singleline);
        var match = regex.Match(str);
        foreach (Group group in match.Groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(group.Value);
        }
```

For `keyverified` and `connected` it works ok and give me respective values but when I change the regString to `@"debug=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"` it only gives me the first word i.e `Not`. I want to extract the whole value like `Not connected and no params`. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookahead, since the items before the equals sign do not contain spaces:

```
@"debug=([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)(?=((\s[A-Za-z0-9])+=|$))"
```

Answer (score 1):

For debug you sould add the space in the regex:

```
@"debug=([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)"
```

you can write in a more compact way as:

```
@"debug=([\w\s]+)"
```

consider that if you have some other field after debug the field name will be matched as well
since you don't have a proper separator between fields.

Comment: That's what I said in the last point. If debug is the last it works. Tim as well propose a much general solution but still it works only if the multi-word field is the last one, the problem here is in the input format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a key may not contain spaces or `=` signs, and that values may not contain `=` signs, you can do this:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @"(?<key>  # Match and capture into group ""key"":
     [^\s=]+   # one or more non-space characters (also, = is not allowed)
    )          # End of group ""key""
    =          # Match =
    (?<value>  # Match and capture into group ""value"":
     [^=]+     # one or more characters except =
     (?=\s|$)  # Assert that the next character is a space or end-of-string
    )          # End of group ""value""", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine("Key: " + matchResult.Groups["key"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Value: " + matchResult.Groups["value"].Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: Did you see that the lines that do something with the matches are commented out? I don't know how you're storing the key/value pairs, so I left that part up to you.

Comment: All key/value pairs are present in the example string. Furthermore, I deleted the commented lines before testing the regex

Comment: No, you needed to *uncomment* them and change them so the captured values will be stored somewhere. I changed them into WriteLines, hope you understand now what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595(v=vs.80).aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match